# Springboot JPA statistics JMX

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, statistics, jmx

I trying to expose a JMX MBean that allow to:
- enable JPA statistics
- disable JPA statistics
- get statistics

I tried to enable statistics:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true

I hoped it will activate an indicator jmx but it didn't work...

I'm looking for a sample project, do you know one?

I'm using springboot 1.5.3.